# How to pass JSP array to Javascript of highchart to generate a column chart

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, highcharts

I am a novice in Highcharts, JSP and Javascript and need your input and suggestion on the issue, I have been struggling since 4-5 days. Please help me.

The issue is I am able to get the 2 output arrays from JSP that I need to pass in the highchart JS for generate a column graph.

```
[99, 90, 87, 82, 80, 77, 70, 65, 65, 60] and
['orcl2','orcl2','orcl2','orcl2','orcl1','orcl1','orcl3','orcl2','orcl3','orcl1']
```

But I am not able to pass the value to the JS to generate the column graph. Following is the entire code that I am using. Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*, java.io.*, java.util.Date, java.util.*,javax.servlet.*, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Calendar " %>
<%  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); %>
 <%
     Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@RAC1.dinu.com:1521:orcl2","cog","cog123");
     Statement statement12 = connection.createStatement();
          ResultSet resultset12 = 
            statement12.executeQuery("select * from(select HOST_NAME,INSTANCE_NAME,PID,PCPU, to_char(TIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from ORA_CPU_STATUS where trunc(TIME)=trunc(sysdate) order by PCPU desc) where rownum<=10");
 %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/2a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/3a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/json2.js"></script>
        <script>
$(function () {
    var chart;

   <%
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
while(resultset12.next())
{
    String val = resultset12.getString(1);
    list.add(val);
    String val2 = resultset12.getString(2);
    list2.add(val2);

String csv = list2.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
String csvWithQuote = list.toString().replace("[", "'").replace("]", "'").replace(", ", "','");
%>
var dincpu = '<%=csv%>';
var dinpcat = '<%=csvWithQuote%>';
var input = JSON.parse("[" + dincpu + "]"),
       data = [],
categories = JSON.parse("[" + dinpcat + "]");
    $.each(input, function(index, value){
        var color;
        if (value > 80) color = 'red';
        else if (value > 60) color = 'Orange';
        else color = 'green';
        data.push({y:value, color: color, url:'https://www.google.com'});
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'COL',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Current Top 10 CPU Consumers',
                    style: {fontSize: '10px'}
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories,
                labels: {
                    rotation: -35,
                    align: 'center'
                }
            },
           yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage',
                    style: {fontSize: '11px'}
                }
            },
            exporting: { enabled: false },
             legend: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>' +'- Oracle User Process CPU Consumed :'+'<b>'+ this.y +' % ' +'</b>' ;
                }
            },
       plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            location.href = this.options.url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
                series: [{
                name: 'CPU Consumed',
        pointWidth: 28,
                data: data

            }]
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="COL" style="min-width: 100px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure where you're going with this code

```
String csv = list2.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
String csvWithQuote = list.toString().replace("[", "'").replace("]", "'").replace(", ", "','");
%>
var dincpu = '<%=csv%>';
var dinpcat = '<%=csvWithQuote%>';
var input = JSON.parse("[" + dincpu + "]"),
       data = [],
categories = JSON.parse("[" + dinpcat + "]");
```

If you have your data in this format:

```
[99, 90, 87, 82, 80, 77, 70, 65, 65, 60] and
['orcl2','orcl2','orcl2','orcl2','orcl1','orcl1','orcl3','orcl2','orcl3','orcl1']
```

Why not do this (remove the 's and get rid of the JSON.parse)?

```
var dincpu = <%=csv%>;
var dinpcat = <%=csvWithQuote%>;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VYLTW/

Comment: the static values works fine, but the dynamic ones are not happening.
I modified the code as:
String csv = list2.toString();
String csvWithQuote = list.toString().replace("[", "['").replace("]", "']").replace(", ", "','");
%>
var dincpu = <%=csv%>;
var dinpcat = <%=csvWithQuote%>;
var input = dincpu,
        data = [],
        categories =dinpcat;

Its throwing error.
=================
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
type Exception report
message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Comment: ignore the error mentioned by me just before this update, I just missed a "}". Now I am getting only the title of the graph and with a horizontal line only, without any column in it.

Comment: If you view sorce on the page, what do you see on the lines for var dincpu = and var dinpcat =?  Are they correct arrays now?  Can you put those values in a fiddle with the rest of your highcharts settings?

Comment: no [] and [''] are the respective results for 
   
var dincpu = [];
var dinpcat = [''];
 
its really wierd ... when I do it seperately in another jsp page and print them they are fetching the data as below:
[99, 90, 87, 82, 80, 77, 70, 65, 65, 60]
['orcl2','orcl2','orcl2','orcl2','orcl1','orcl1','orcl3','orcl2','orcl3','orcl1']

Comment: The array is also not getting printed outside the servlet <% %>.

Comment: I would add log messages of the variables in your server side code to see where you're losing the values.  I'd start before and after the replace statements.

Comment: output before the replace stmt:
[99, 90, 87, 82, 80, 77, 70, 65, 65, 60]
[orcl2,orcl2,orcl2,orcl2,orcl1,orcl1,orcl3,orcl2,orcl3,orcl1]

After the the replace stmt:
[99, 90, 87, 82, 80, 77, 70, 65, 65, 60]
['orcl2','orcl2','orcl2','orcl2','orcl1','orcl1','orcl3','orcl2','orcl3','orcl1']

Comment: the result is not getting passed to the JS .

Comment: Try adding an alert in your javascript code: alert("<%=csv%>"); Do you get the expected result?

Comment: it gives a blank [] only.

Answer (score 0):

@Barbara,
it worked finally with

```
var dincpu = <%=csv%>;
var dinpcat = <%=csvWithQuote%>;
```

along with the fiddle that you gave http://jsfiddle.net/VYLTW/  .
I am putting the entire code in Answer that actually worked.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*, java.io.*, java.util.Date, java.util.*,javax.servlet.*, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Calendar " %>
<%  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); %>
 <%
     Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@RAC1.dinu.com:1521:orcl2","cog","cog123");
     Statement statement12 = connection.createStatement();
          ResultSet resultset12 = 
            statement12.executeQuery("select * from(select INSTANCE_NAME,PCPU from ORA_CPU_STATUS order by PCPU desc) where rownum<=10");


List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
while(resultset12.next())
{
    String val = resultset12.getString(1);
    list.add(val);
    String val2 = resultset12.getString(2);
    list2.add(val2);

}

String csv = list2.toString();
String csvWithQuote = list.toString().replace("[", "['").replace("]", "']").replace(", ", "','");

%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/2a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/3a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DBdashboard/json2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var dincpu=<%=csv%>;
    var dinpcat = <%=csvWithQuote%>;
    var input = dincpu,
        data = [],
        categories =dinpcat;
        $.each(input, function(index, value){
            var color;
            if (value > 80) color = 'red';
            else if (value > 60) color = 'Orange';
            else color = 'green';
            data.push({y:value, color: color, url:'https://www.google.com'});
        });

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'COL',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Current Top 10 CPU Consumers',
            style: {fontSize: '10px'}
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories,
            labels: {
                rotation: -35,
                align: 'center'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage',
                style: {fontSize: '11px'}
            }
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>' +'- Oracle User Process CPU Consumed :'+'<b>'+ this.y +' % ' +'</b>' ;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            location.href = this.options.url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'CPU Consumed',
            pointWidth: 28,
            data: data

        }]
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="COL" style="min-width: 100px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Barbara, 
1) If you see the latest code I have put all the JSP scriptlet "<% %>" at the top and then called the

```
var dincpu = <%=csv%>;
var dinpcat = <%=csvWithQuote%>;
```

After which I could see in view source of the webpage that the values are getting passed to the JS variables in the JS function. 
2) Then put the same JS code that you have put in the fiddle. 
3) I felt that the function $(document).ready(function()  was causing problem which I removed. 
And another important thing is that since I was putting all my code in a virtual linux box, there might be some hidden characters thats getting copied while I was coping from windows text editor (Editplus).

I found all those 3 things were responsible for the issue.